# How to indicate recording process in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am recording voices in my application. I need to indicate, that my voice is recording. How to proceed with this in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, initialize a timer and load an indicator view till you get the response of completion from your voice recorder method. increment the timer eventually by checking the method response.